# test if list contains a number in some range

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a list `L=[1.1, 1.8, 4.4, 5.2]`.  For some integer, `n`, I want to know whether `L` has a value `val` with `n-1<val<n+1`, and if so I want to know the index of `val`.

The best I can do so far is to define a generator

```
x = (index for index,val in enumerate(L) if n-1<val<n+1)
```

and check to see whether it has an appropriate value using `try... except`.  So let's assume I'm looking for the smallest n>=0 for which such a value exists...

```
L=[1.1, 1.8, 4.4, 5.2]
n=0
while True:
    x = (index for index,val in enumerate(L) if n-1<val<n+1)
    try:
        index=next(x)
        break
    except StopIteration:
        n+=1
print n,index
```

> 1 0

In reality, I'm doing a more complicated task.  I'll want to be able to take an n, find the first index, and if it doesn't exist, I need to do something else.

This doesn't seem like particularly clean code to me.  Is there a better way?  I feel like numpy probably has the answer, but I don't know it well enough.

Comment: possible duplicate of [First Python list index greater than x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236906/first-python-list-index-greater-than-x)

Comment: don't think so - want first greater than n-1, less than n+1 and how to handle if it doesn't exist (quickly)

Comment: It's not very clear what you expect if the item doesn't exist

Comment: If the item doesn't exist, in my example, I just increase `n` by 1.  More generally I want to either get the index, or if it doesn't exist I want to perform some other action.

Comment: But n is an input, why would you make it an output? Anyways, you can use `next((index for index,val in enumerate(L) if n-1<val<n+1), n + 1)` second parameter to get the default

Comment: your question says you want to know "the" index of the value.  What if there is more than one?  All indicies or just the first?    Also, how large is your list, if it's not large then you probably don't need np,  if it's very large than memory and speed start to dictate the best answer.

Comment: Because I want to know the first `n` for which such a value exists.

Comment: @PhilCooper just the first, thanks.

Comment: Just copy the list to integer with rounding down and look for the first matching integer.  If you have a  .00 then is it will never satisfy the condition so need to deal with that.

Answer (score 4):

If L is sorted, you could use `bisect.bisect_left` to find the index i for which all L[< i] < n <= all L[>= i].

Then

```
if n - L[i-1] < 1.0:
    val = L[i-1]
elif L[i] - n < 1.0:
    val = L[i]
else:
    val = None     # no such value found
```

---

**Edit:** Depending on your data, what you want to accomplish, and how much time you want to spend writing a clever algorithm, sorting *may or may not* be a good solution for you; and before I see too many more O(n)s waved around, I would like to point out that his actual problem seems to involve repeatedly probing for various values of n - which would pretty rapidly amortize the initial sorting overhead - and that his suggested algorithm above is actually O(n**2).

@AntoinePelisse: by all means, let's do some profiling:

```
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right
from functools import partial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import randint, uniform
from timeit import timeit

#blues    
density_col_lin = [
    (0.000, 0.502, 0.000, 1.000),
    (0.176, 0.176, 0.600, 1.000),
    (0.357, 0.357, 0.698, 1.000),
    (0.537, 0.537, 0.800, 1.000)
]

# greens
density_col_sor = [
    (0.000, 0.502, 0.000, 1.000),
    (0.176, 0.600, 0.176, 1.000),
    (0.357, 0.698, 0.357, 1.000),
    (0.537, 0.800, 0.537, 1.000)
]

def make_data(length, density):
    max_ = length / density
    return [uniform(0.0, max_) for _ in range(length)], max_

def linear_probe(L, max_, probes):
    for p in range(probes):
        n = randint(0, int(max_))
        for index,val in enumerate(L):
            if n - 1.0 < val < n + 1.0:
                # return index
                break

def sorted_probe(L, max_, probes):
    # initial sort
    sL = sorted((val,index) for index,val in enumerate(L))
    for p in range(probes):
        n = randint(0, int(max_))
        left  = bisect_right(sL, (n - 1.0, max_))
        right = bisect_left (sL, (n + 1.0, 0.0 ), left)
        if left < right:
            index = min(sL[left:right], key=lambda s:s[1])[1]
            # return index

def main():
    densities = [0.8, 0.2, 0.08, 0.02]
    probes    = [1, 3, 10, 30, 100]
    lengths   = [[]                   for d in densities]
    lin_pts   = [[[] for p in probes] for d in densities]
    sor_pts   = [[[] for p in probes] for d in densities]

    # time each function at various data lengths, densities, and probe repetitions
    for d,density in enumerate(densities):
        for trial in range(200):
            print("{}-{}".format(density, trial))

             # length in 10 to 5000, with log density
            length = int(10 ** uniform(1.0, 3.699))
            L, max_ = make_data(length, density)
            lengths[d].append(length)

            for p,probe in enumerate(probes):
                lin = timeit(partial(linear_probe, L, max_, probe), number=5) / 5
                sor = timeit(partial(sorted_probe, L, max_, probe), number=5) / 5
                lin_pts[d][p].append(lin / probe)
                sor_pts[d][p].append(sor / probe)

    # plot the results
    plt.figure(figsize=(9.,6.))
    plt.axis([0, 5000, 0, 0.004])

    for d,density in enumerate(densities):
        xs = lengths[d]
        lcol = density_col_lin[d]
        scol = density_col_sor[d]

        for p,probe in enumerate(probes):
            plt.plot(xs, lin_pts[d][p], "o", color=lcol, markersize=4.0)
            plt.plot(xs, sor_pts[d][p], "o", color=scol, markersize=4.0)

    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which results in

[image]

x-axis is number of items in L, y-axis is amortized time per probe; green dots are sorted_probe(), blue are linear_probe().

Conclusions:

- runtimes for both functions are remarkably linear with respect to length
- for a single probe into L, presorting is about 4 times slower than iterating
- the crossover point seems to be about 5 probes; for fewer than that, linear search is faster, for more, presorting is faster.

Comment: I can't assume sorted.

Comment: @Joel: then either you sort it, or you have to compare every list item.

Comment: interesting that you would recommend using a O(n lg n) solution before O(n)

Comment: @AntoinePelisse: depending on the relative constant and the length of his list, yes, the "slow" method may well be faster.

Comment: @HughBothwell Could you provide an example? I'd be very curious to investigate one? Sorting means that you have to read all values from the list while going one-by-one is going to be cache-optimal and most of the time won't even go for a full read.

Comment: @HughBothwell I am really missing why you feel O(n ln n) is at all necessary.  Maybe you answered before OP said he just wanted the first element that satified the result.  
Worst case should be O(n)  Average should be O(n/2) since you are just looking for one (first satisfying value)
I would -1 because I think this is the wrong approach but then I'd +1 because most people overlook bisect and it's nice to have it called out.

Comment: Of course, if he wants to probe multiple times (let's call it `p`), he going to end-up with: `O((n + p) lg n)` for sorting against `O(np)` for simple search. It's important to describe the problem correctly :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that doesn't rely on `try`... `except` and is relatively easy-to-read.  As a result it "feels cleaner" to me, but that's always going to have an element of subjectivity to it.

```
def where_within_range( sequence, lower, upper ):
    for index, value in enumerate( sequence ):
        if lower < value < upper: return index

L = [ 1.1, 1.8, 4.4, 5.2 ]

import itertools
for n in itertools.count():
    index = where_within_range( L, n - 1, n + 1 )
    if index != None: break

print n, index
```

If you'd prefer to avoid the repeated-function-call overhead you could instead do it as follows, which once again uses the `StopIteration` exception but by using `itertools.count` and a `return` statement, (again, "somehow") ends up seeming cleaner to me. Perhaps it's because there's only one statement in each part of the `try`...`except`... clause (there's not much rational basis for that feeling, admittedly).

```
import itertools
def find_joel_root( sequence ):
    for n in itertools.count():
        solutions = ( index for index, value in enumerate( sequence ) if n - 1 < value < n + 1 )
        try: return n, next( solutions )
        except StopIteration: pass

L = [ 1.1, 1.8, 4.4, 5.2 ]
n, index = find_joel_root( L )
print n, index
```

Answer (score 2):

I have an interesting thought, by using `defaultdict` and build the index with the values `(n-1)` and `(n+1)`, it will require looping the list once, and thereafter just compare the key/values, like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

L = [1.1, 1.8, 4.4, 5.2]

x = defaultdict(dict)
for idx, item in enumerate(L):
    x[int(item)] = {int(item-1): item-1, int(item+1): item+1, 'index':idx}
```

Usage:

```
n = 5

x[n].get(n-1) < n < x[n].get(n+1) and x[n]['index']
Out[8]: 3

n = 2

x[n].get(n-1) < n < x[n].get(n+1) and x[n]['index']
Out[10]: False
```

Explanation:

As if:

1) `True` and **Index** returns **Index**

2) `False` and **Index** will return `False`

Because you are going to input `n` as an integer, if first part is `True` it will return the second part `index` value. If first part fails, it returns `False`.

This will return the *LAST* occurrence of `n`, in case you need the *FIRST* occurrence of `n`, just reversed the list and **Index**:

```
...
l = len(L)
for idx, item in enumerate(reversed(L)):
    x[int(item)] = {int(item-1): item-1, 
                    int(item+1): item+1, 
                    'index': l-idx-1}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Now,when I think,that I finally understand your task : 
just find the minimum value in the array and it's index - n will be equal to cell(mininum). 
Or even simpler :

```
n,index = int(min(L)),L.index(min(L))
```

Comment: @Joel can you have a look at my code now? I think this will work fine

Answer (score 1):

`l` can be a list or numpy array:

```
next(((i,v) for i,v in enumerate(l) if n-1<v<n+1))
```

uses generators and stops on the first value.