# index of a first occurrence (inequality match) in a list

Tags: python, list

```
A=[2,3,5,7,11,13]
print(A.index(5))
```

The answer is 2,
But what I need is the first one which is bigger than 4 (the answer will be the same - 2).
I can apply a while loop, but is there a more elegant or a builtin way to do it?
In my problem the list is sorted in an ascending order (no duplication),
and my target is to split it into two lists: lower or equal to 4, and bigger than 4; and given the list is sorted it would be redundant to scan it twice (or even once).

Comment: Use the bisect module.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [First Python list index greater than x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236906/first-python-list-index-greater-than-x)

Comment: @J.Bergmann Nope, that's not sorted.

Answer (score 5):

As @DanD.mentioned, you can use the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module for this, in you example you can use [`bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left)

```
>>> import bisect
>>> bisect.bisect_left(A, 5)
2
```

This will use a binary search since your data is sorted, which will be faster than a linear search (`O(logN)` instead of `O(N)`).

If you want the index of the first value greater than `4`, then you can switch to [`bisect_right`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_right)

```
>>> bisect.bisect_right(A, 4)
2
```

Comment: For splitting the list into "lower or equal" and "bigger", on the other hand, `bisect_right` should be used.

Answer (score 3):

You're totally correct about efficiency - if you have *already sorted* list, do not iterate linearly, its waste of time

There's built-in `bisect` module - exactly for binary search in sorted containers.

You're probably looking for [`bisect_right`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_right) function.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody, the answer using your kind help is:

```
import bisect
A=[2,3,5,7,11,13]
N=bisect.bisect_right(A,4)
print(A[:N]) #[2,3]
print(A[N:]) #[5,7,11,13]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) with a default argument:

```
val = next((i for i, x in enumerate(A) if x > 4), len(A))
```

Given the above result, you can then do:

```
left, right = A[:val], A[val:]
```

Comment: Is `False` a good default here? When not explicitly checked with `is`, it will be interpreted as `0`. IMHO better use `-1` (also has to be checked, but more standard), `None`, or just no default.

Comment: @tobias_k It might be not intuitive **but** `[2, 3, 4][False:]` returns `[2, 3, 4]` which is what you want to have. That would not happen with `-1` (`[4]`). `0` would also work just fine.

Comment: Actually, no, because `A[False:]` should return the elements that are _larger_ than `4`, i.e. `[]` in your example. So, for the slicing case _only_, `len(A)` would be a better default.

Comment: @tobias_k Oh, yeah. Thanks for noticing. Then how about `len(A)` as a default?