# First pandas DataFrame column index greater than x

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know to cast pandas DataFrame column to a list (with `.tolist()` or `list()`) and then do what you want, will make it way much slower, so I don't want to use [these methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236906/first-python-list-index-greater-than-x).

I want to find the index of the first element of a pandas DataFrame column which is equal or greater than a value `x`, in other words `>=x`. And if there is nothing then return `None`.

For example, if the column is this and our function is called `first_greater()`:

```
    0
0   1
1  -5
2   6
3   4
4  -7
5  12
6  -2
7   0
8  -3
```

Then we have:

```
first_greater(-5) = 0
first_greater(7) = 5
first_greater(4) = 2
first_greater(6) = 2
first_greater(22) = None
```

I'm new to pandas and I don't know how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to check both if any value in the dataframe is greater than the given value, and also return the first value that satsfies the condition. You have `idxmax` for that:

```
def first_greater(df, n, col):
    m = df.col.ge(n)
    return m.any() and m.idxmax()
```

---

Note that in the return statement, the right part of the `and` is only evaluated if the first condition `m.any()` is satisfied, otherwise `False` is returned.

---

Let's check with the proposed examples:

```
first_greater(df, 5, 'col1')
# 0

first_greater(df, 7, 'col1')
# 5

first_greater(df, 4, 'col1')
# 2

first_greater(df, 6, 'col1')
# 2

first_greater(df, 22, 'col1')
# False
```

---

Input data -

```
    col1
0     1
1    -5
2     6
3     4
4    -7
5    12
6    -2
7     0
8    -3
```

Comment: we want to return None not False if nothing is greater

Comment: The problem with that is that nothing is returned from the function, so I think a boolean value or a string of some kind is more useful as an indicator than `None`@dan

Comment: Your welcome @Peymanmohsenikiasari note that the `and` can be changed into an `if else` statement, which would make it easier if you want to return `None` or a specific string. Otherwise if `False` works this is clean and simple

Comment: How is `first_greater(df, 6, 'col1')` 2? it should be 5 right?

Comment: I was following OPs logic, that's why I'm using `ge`("greater or equal") @SH-SF

Answer (score 1):

```
s = pd.Series([1, -5, 6, 4, -7, 12, -2, 0, -3])

def first_greater(n):
    condition = (s >= n)
    if condition.any():
        return condition.idxmax()
    else:
        return None
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you have the answer already. But just another approach to show the possibilities

```
def fg(n):
try:
    a = df.loc[df.col1.ge(n)].index[0]
    return a
except:
    print('None')
```

Comment: Thank you. but I thing invoking an exception can make your process much slower.

Comment: agreed. I was just trying something & found this approach. Since i am learning pandas myself, thought of sharing. That's all.