# Finding list indexes of numbers greater than a value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How to get the index of a number in a python list if we have some condition:

```
    test_list=[1,5,7,11,20,26,89]
    # find index of number>13
```

**Ans: 4** (index value)

Comment: Did you remember to search before asking? There are a number of suitable solutions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236906/first-python-list-index-greater-than-x) post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply iterate through the list and break when you condition is true:

```
test_list = [1,5,7,11,20,26,89]
for i, value in enumerate(test_list):
    if value > 13:
        break

print(value)  # 20
print(i)      # 4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use numpy in the following way:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,5,7,11,20,26,89])
x[np.where(x>13)][0]  # 20
```

Note that you ask for the index but you wish the value, so in case you wish the index:

```
np.where(x>13)[0]  # array([4, 5, 6])
```

will give you all the indices the meets the condition

Comment: sorry, I want the index

Comment: @yashcode17 so just using `np.where(x>13)` will give you what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in index method. For example:

```
test_list = [1,5,7,11,20,26,89]
test_list.index(5)
```

will return 1.
So you can use that in the following manner to get the desired result:

```
for i in test_list:
    if i > 13:
        print(test_list.index(i))
```

Edit: Added how to use the index method to meet the requirements of the question

Comment: `index()` doesn't get a condition so it won't really help him unless he knows the value

Comment: @DavidS I updated my answer to include one of the many ways one can go about using the index method while checking for conditions.