# Finding index of nested list greater than a value

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list

`l1 = [ [0.1*x, 0.5*x] for x in range(6) ]`

which gives

`[[0.0, 0.0], [0.1, 0.5], [0.2, 1.0], [0.3, 1.5], [0.4, 2.0], [0.5, 2.5]]`

Let's say `val=0.35` is a variable. I am trying to find smallest index `x` such that of `l1[x][0]>val`, which is `4` in this case.

I want to use the iterator approach given here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2236935/11638153

Comment: what's stopping you from simply iterating through the list and comparing?

Comment: @rcshon  execution time

Comment: this is a simple linear-time operation just with the option of early stopping. Execution time shouldn't be a concern in cases like this unless you're doing something like HFT, which I doubt is the case since Python.

Comment: A simple iteration with early stopping like @NYC Coder's answer works better if somehow execution time is really a concern, probably the fastest way to natively solve your problem without involving Cython. Since there is a conditional check, the iterator/generator approach requires going through the full list to check your condition before calling `next` only to return the first element, losing the benefit of early stopping, hence slower.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of doing using a method:

```
def get_smallest_index(list1):
    for i, l in enumerate(list1):
        if l[0] > val:
            return i
    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    l1 = [[0.1*x, 0.5*x] for x in range(6)]
    val = 0.35
    print(get_smallest_index(l1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `min` - function together with `enumerate` with a comprehension to achive that:

```
values = [[0.0, 0.0], [0.1, 0.5], [0.2, 1.0], [0.3, 1.5], [0.4, 2.0], [0.5, 2.5]]

k = 0.35
idx = min( i for i,v in enumerate(values) if v[0] > k)

print(idx)
```

gives you

```
4
```

This will be suboptimal though, it is kindof better to use a normal loop with enumerate and break from it because *this* code has to iterate all elements, the loop can finish as soon as the first value is found.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to convert to a `NumPy` array, you could do:

```
l1 = np.array(l1)
val = 0.35

try:
  idx = np.where(l1[:, 0] > val)[0][0]
except:
  idx = None
```

The `try, except` block is just to catch the case where no `idx` in `l1` meets the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using `next(x[0] for x in enumerate(l11) if x[1][0] > val )`