# Find first instance of when a datetime value is greater than another. Datetime value is deep within an object generated by sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I have used sqlalchemy to retrive data from my database and store it within an object. I now need to find the first line where a datetime ('created_at') value is greater than another that I provide. The data is in this format.

```
{id: 1, 'user': 1, 'setpoints' : [{setpoint1, setpoint2}], 'data':[{'created_at': '2022-06-10 12:00:00', 'data': {data1, data2}]}
```

I have tried using this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236906/first-python-list-index-greater-than-x), and I have made a mistake somewhere, but I do not understand the answer enough to adapt it for my situation.

I wrote this:

```
startPos = next((i for i, v in enumerate(hardware['data']) if datetime.strptime(v['created_at'],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') > startTime), None)
```

Could anybody please explain where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

your datetime format in `created_at` is not in a correct `isoformat`.

your data is `2022-06-10 12:00:00` but the `isoformat` itself is `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S`.

You already write it right at the format above but wrong in the data you have.

So it should be `2022-06-10T12:00:00`