# Find index of first value less than threshold for all columns

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a dataframe where, for each column, I need to find the index of the first value less than 5. I found a solution that works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236906/first-python-list-index-greater-than-x) for an individual list/series, but can't apply it to an entire dataframe in a 'pythony' way without breaking each column into its own variable via a for loop.

```
Data = pd.DataFrame({0: [2,2,3,2,2,3,5],
    1: [8,7,7,8,7,7,7],
    2: [9,7,7,4,4,4,9]})
```

The desired output would be [0,999,3] where 999 is a flag for not finding a value < 5.
This code works for an individual series/list:

```
next((x for x, val in enumerate(DataS) if val < 5),999)
```

but when I try to apply this over all the columns I can't get it to work:

```
Data.apply(lambda x: next((x for x, val in enumerate(Data) if val < 5),999))
```

This code returns a value of 0 for every column. Can someone help me understand why apply/lambda aren't behaving how I think they should?

As a bonus, this function also appears to skip over nan values. Is there a different way to write this to flag nans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us use `idxmax` to find the index of values < `5`, then mask the index with `999` if there is no such value < `5`

```
m = df.lt(5)
m.idxmax().where(m.any(), 999)
```

---

```
0      0
1    999
2      3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Works great, thanks. Always seems to be an easier solution.