# given a sorted list, find the index of number

Tags: python, list

Given a `sorted list` and a number `n`, **find the index in the list** that precedes `n` in the most efficient (fastest) way.

sorted list example:

```
x_list = [1, 3.5, 5, 9.2, 20, 50.75]
```

number `n`, say n = 7.5

Example answer: the index of the value in the list that precedes `n` is `2`.

This is what i have tried so far:

```
x_list = [1, 3.5, 5, 9.2, 20, 50.75]

n = 7.5
for i, v in enumerate(x_list):
    if v < n: xlow = i
    else: break
print(xlow)
```

Can i do a quicker find than the above method ?

Note:
This list is `sorted` whereas other questions of the same nature are `unsorted`.

Comment: [Binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

Comment: @MechanicPig,  that looks better for large lists. How to implement this ?

Comment: have a look at [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module from standard library

Comment: Does this answer your question? [First Python list index greater than x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236906/first-python-list-index-greater-than-x)

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew,  this looks great,  but is less efficient than bisect from what i can see.

Comment: One of the solution in the post is about bisect too, I think you can do a performance check for the top answer and the bisect with large list :D

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew Sorting is no mention in that question, so this is not a duplicate. On the contrary, I think this problem is suitable to be a canonical duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) to perform a binary search:

```
import bisect

n = 7.5

index = bisect.bisect_left(x_list, n)-1
```

output: `2`

*NB. In case the target is before the first index, this will return `-1`, which you can avoid using `max(0, bisect.bisect_left(x_list, n)-1)` if needed.*